# ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core (Ubuntu xgboost installation)

Tags: python, numpy, github, ubuntu-14.04, xgboost

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version alongside Windows 10.

My PC configs are: 4 GB RAM, 64 bit

I installed Anaconda after downloading the file using:
bash Anaconda3-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

Installation was successful.

Now in my ubuntu terminal, I follwed steps as instructed on http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html#building-on-ubuntu-debian

1. Installed a recent GNU C++ compiler  -->successful
2. git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
   cd xgboost; make -j4

Building was also successful and I could build 'libxgboost.so'

3. sudo apt-get install python-setuptools  (Successful)
4. cd python-package
5. sudo python setup.py install

The 5. command returns an error after a lot of lines:

'ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core'

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this error so that I can install xgboost ?

Comment: Can anyone help please? I am still stuck on this and can't install xgboost. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem today.  I believe the issue is the instructions you listed are out of date for Python installs, as they are now enabled with `pip install`.

Delete the `xgboost` directory that your above install attempt created, and then execute:

```
pip install xgboost
```

It should all work with one command. See also the [Python Specific XGBoost Install Instructions](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package).

Answer (score 3):

This issue is listed in [xgboost's github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/820)

The solution is

> sudo -s
>
> python setup.py install

instead of

> cd python-package; sudo python setup.py install